# Does plan recompilation happens to plan guide?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, execution-plan, plan-guides, recompile

Does plan recompilation happens for plan guide due to the, for example, auto update stats?

P.S Do **not** take into account adding a hint **OPTION (RECOMPILE)** in the plan guide

Comment: A plan guide basically forces to use that plan no matter what .. so no a recompilation wont affect plan guide. Best is to test out and see the actual behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, a plan guide is not compiled like an execution plan. Therefore, it cannot be recompiled. That being said, a plan guide does result in an execution plan, either through its hints or by specifying a specific plan to use. The resulting or specified execution plan could be affected by auto update statistics.

If auto update statistics determines that a statistics update is necessary, query plans dependent on those statistics would be recompiled.